# Scatterplot of several columns of a datatable

Tags: r, datatable, scatter-plot

Out of a datatable with 20 rows and 6 columns, I want to plot a scatterplot of column 2 and 4. Column 1 is the row ID from 0 to 19. 
In the table description it is written Factor with 20 levels for column 1 and 2, and num for column 4

I already tried to convert a single column with as.factor to a single data file, and then merge together and plot with ggplot. This does not work for me.

```
BasinSize <- as.factor(Table_Barrow20$`Lake Size`) #column2 of table
Basinheight <- as.factor(Table_Barrow20$`Lake Mean`) #column 4 of table
scatterdata <- merge(Basinheight, BasinSize)

plot(scatterdata)
ggplot(scatterdata, aes(x=Basinheight, y=BasinSize), col=c("33FF00")) + 
  geom_point(shape=18)
```

The problem is, that the two columns merge together in a wrong way, by combining all 20 values with 20 values instead of merging by ID.

Here is the table copied from a .txt

"Name" "Lake Size" "Max" "Mean" "Med" "Min"
"1" "0" "2419723" 9.37238597869873 6.85431201700351 6.79038763046265 5.5892276763916
"2" "1" "737345" 2.20990252494812 1.17229168051113 1.16918420791626 0.532729208469391
"3" "2" "1904419" 6.97486448287964 6.29653060932372 6.29239559173584 5.74258995056152
"4" "3" "633220" 2.94963598251343 0.693283292837505 0.566755801439285 -1.04891955852509
"5" "4" "3417157" 2.02893280982971 1.04370415649172 1.16990214586258 -0.615132451057434
"6" "5" "3046643" 2.39258670806885 0.612889545533382 0.621234953403473 -2.27862739562988
"7" "6" "3868608" 16.8747043609619 15.986930145805 15.9581031799316 14.7309837341309
"8" "7" "11952064" 4.12359857559204 3.50676135545307 3.50302672386169 2.70154309272766
"9" "8" "2431961" 6.02156400680542 4.79594737052494 4.82516670227051 3.39997673034668
"10" "9" "5624563" 7.80270195007324 6.76836155530465 6.72958827018738 5.68962478637695
"11" "10" "2430490" 4.87959337234497 3.43340588038286 3.3837513923645 2.91182518005371
"12" "12" "1436097" 3.67803716659546 2.49129957226396 2.47576546669006 1.17649579048157
"13" "13" "791941" 5.25690269470215 4.07207433426663 4.07166481018066 3.61373019218445
"14" "14" "3013737" 1.69542956352234 0.756966933677959 0.755697637796402 -2.0527184009552
"15" "15" "2594511" 5.87903642654419 2.43693244171563 2.44506788253784 0.725884079933167
"16" "16" "3105136" 12.6303310394287 9.71669491262446 9.67505931854248 8.92571830749512
"17" "17" "1985544" 9.32382488250732 8.25899538392204 8.30398368835449 6.08988952636719
"18" "18" "1800122" 12.424147605896 8.48729049871582 8.50036954879761 7.7384238243103
"19" "19" "2753803" 16.724292755127 15.7803085039918 15.7673816680908 14.8390283584595
"20" "11" "765907" 3.45813465118408 2.61115002320832 2.59490370750427 2.17101335525513

Comment: Maybe try using `cbind` instead of `merge`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn`t work. The problem is, that I have to somehow integrate the ID (column 1) to the data of the two other columns. Either to each column itself or the three columns together. 
Or there might be another way to plot the data directly from the table to a scatterplot.

Comment: Can you post a few lines from your dataframe Table_Barrow20 so I can reproduce what is happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should use factor because using geom_point, you would want numerical features for x and y

This should work :

```
ggplot(Table_Barrow20, aes(x=as.numeric(`Lake Size`), y=as.numeric(`Lake Mean`)), col=c("33FF00")) + 
  geom_point(shape=18)
```

Update if you have multiple geom_point, you can put your dataframe in tidy format :

```
library(tidyverse)
Table_Barrow20  <- data.frame(Buffer.Mean=c(1,2,4),Buffer.Size=c(10,30,20),Lake.Mean=c(3,1,4),Lake.Size=c(15,25,12))
# select columns about buffer and add type variable
df1 <- Table_Barrow20 %>% 
          select(Buffer.Mean,Buffer.Size) %>% 
          rename(Mean=Buffer.Mean,Size=Buffer.Size) %>% 
          mutate(type="Buffer") %>% 
          mutate(Size=as.numeric(Size), Mean=as.numeric(Mean))
# select columns about lake and add type variable
df2 <- Table_Barrow20 %>% 
          select(Lake.Mean,Lake.Size) %>% 
          rename(Mean=Lake.Mean,Size=Lake.Size) %>% 
          mutate(type="Lake") %>% 
          mutate(Size=as.numeric(Size), Mean=as.numeric(Mean))
# bind the two dataframe to make one with all lines
df_tot <- rbind(df1,df2) 
# add "type" column as color so the colors will be different for lake and buffer
ggplot(df_tot, aes(x=Size, y=Mean, col=type)) + 
  geom_point(shape=18)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That works pretty good. Do you also know how to plot two scatterplots in one diagram? Like the points of column 2 and 4 in one plot, but adding points of two other columns, which are within the same values as the first ones?

Comment: you can just add `+geom_point(aes(x= as.numeric(col1),y=as.numeric(col2)))`

Comment: with this just the additional points are showing up, but not the first ones anymore. I would need them in two different colours then also. 
this is what I used now: 
`ggplot(Table_Barrow20, aes(x=as.numeric(`Lake.Size`), y=as.numeric(`Lake.Mean`))) + 
  geom_point(aes(x= as.numeric(`Buffer.Size`), y=as.numeric(`Buffer.Mean`))) +
  labs(title= "Scatterplot Basin size vs. height", x= "Basin size", y="Basin height")`

Answer (score 0):

Because the two fields come from the same datatable, there's probably no need to merge them separately, you can just call them in your ggplot call ie:

```
Table_Barrow20 = data.frame(LakeSize = rnorm(50,2),
               LakeMean = rnorm(50, 3))

 ggplot(Table_Barrow20, aes(x=LakeMean, y=LakeSize), col=c("33FF00")) + 
     geom_point(shape=18)
```

You also might want to consider casting your numbers as.numeric() since a scatterplot isn't the best way to display factor type data and the data you present looks like it is continuous.